# Collision detection between a capped cylinder and an AABB?

Tags: math, collision-detection

I'm making a game where the player is an upright capped cylinder, and the world is axis aligned bounding boxes. Given this, how could I check if the cylinder is intersecting a box?

Thanks

Comment: Previously: [Collision detection between 2 rotated cubes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651613/), [Collision detection between two general hexahedrons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648285/) and an earlier version now deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly a 2D problem.

For each AABB, test that the vertical dimensions of the cylinder overlap the vertical dimensions of the AABB.  If so, then the test reduces to a 2D case, otherwise, there's no collision.

Then, in the 2D case you need to find if your circle intersects a rectangle... and I'll just refer you to here:

[Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection)