# 3D Line - Plane intersection?

Tags: math, geometry, line, plane

I am having two Vectors (X,Y,Z), one above `Y=0` and one below `Y=0`.
I want to find the Vector (X,Y,Z) where the line between the two original vectors intersects with the `Y=0` level.
How do I do that?

Example Point A:

```
X = -43.54235
Y = 95.2679138
Z = -98.2120361
```

Example Point B:

```
X = -43.54235
Y = 97.23531
Z = -96.24464
```

These points read from two UnProjections from a users click and I'm trying to target the unprojection to `Y=0`.

(I found [3D line plane intersection, with simple plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447361/3d-line-plane-intersection-with-simple-plane) but didn't understand the accepted answer as it's for 2D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that by two vectors, you really mean two points, and want to intersect the line connecting those two points with the plane defined by `Y=0`.

If that's the case, then you could use the definition of a line between two points:

`<A + (D - A)*u, B + (E - B)*u, C + (F - C)*u>`

Where `<A,B,C>` is one of your points and `<D,E,F>` is the other point.  `u` is an undefined scalar that is used to calculate the points along this line.

Since you're intersecting this line with the plane `Y=0`, you simply need to find the point on the line where the "Y" segment is 0.

Specifically, solve for `u` in `B + (E - B)*u = 0`, and then feed that back into the original line equation to find the X and Z components.

Comment: I don't understand. How do I define the line when I don't know u yet? Additionaly, how would I apply that scalar in case I eventually got it?

Comment: `u` is an unknown; let me try to put it this way: A line could be thought of as just a bunch of points that "line" up.  Right?  `u` is the way of finding any specific point on the line you're looking for.  And you're trying to find the single point that lies on the `Y=0` plane.  Once you have `u` (which can be found because you know you want the value of `u` that makes your `Y=0` clause true), just substitute into `A + (D - A)*u` to get X, or into `C + (F - C)*u` to get Z.

Comment: I don't see how I would be getting the scalar for `Y=0` from `-B / (E - B)`. Currently it looks like that scalar scales farer away from Y=0 than closer to it.

Comment: If you use `u = -B / (E - B)` and substitute that into your original point-on-a-line equation `<A + (D - A)*u, B + (E - B)*u, C + (F - C)*u>`, you'll end up with the point on the line between your two points that intersects at `Y=0`.

Comment: From a visual standpoint, your `u` value is how far "between" your two points the intersection with `Y=0` occurs at.  For instance, if `u=0`, then `<A,B,C>` is at `Y=0`.  If `u=1`, then `<D,E,F>` is at `Y=0`.  If `u=0.5`, then `Y=0` is exactly between the two points.  If `u=2.0`, then `Y=0` is closer to your second point, but is an extra length away that is equal to and in the direction of the distance between your points.  The buzzword for this is "interpolation".

Comment: In my case `u ~= -46` so it would be closer to the first point, right? Applying u back to X and Z doesnt change X at all and scales Z up relatively. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are your two points?  That's the only way to help you with respect to real numbers :)  And no, X not changing at all isn't unreasonable if your two points have the same X coordinate.  And Z scaling relatively is also reasonable.

Comment: My points vary on where the user clicks on the screen. I'm unprojecting that click successfully to somewhere at far Y positive. By having a near and a far unprojection I am making out u. Anyways, I'll add example values from a debug right away to the question.

Comment: OK well, looks like its more likely that my unprojection code has a bug or two as it works better with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The equation for the line is

```
(x–x1)/(x2–x1)  = (y–y1)/(y2–y1) = (z–z1)/(z2–z1)
```

So making y=0 yields your coordinates for the intersection.

```
x = -y1 * (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) + x1
```

and

```
z = -y1 * (z2-z1) /(y2-y1) + z1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `float z = -y1 * (z2 - z1) / (y2 - y1) + z1;`?

Comment: @user8709 Yup. Thanks. Corrected