# Ray - plane intersection

Tags: raytracing, plane

I have the following problem that I am unable to solve, even after a long search on the internet.

How calculates the intersection of the plane in ray?

The plane is described by four points:

```
A (ax, ay, 0)
B (bx, by, 0)
C (cx, cy, 0)
D (dx, dy, 0)
```

Ray have:

```
Vector3f origin;
Vector3f direction;
```

And now, i want write a method for checking HIT.
Could someone show me a solution?

```
public Boolean checkHit(Ray myRay){
.
.
.    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666222/3d-line-plane-intersection

Comment: @SlySherZ Thank you for your reply (the link I've seen), but I do not understand it and I am not able to apply to my problem.

Comment: You know three points define a plane, not four.

Comment: i kow, but ho can i write it?

Comment: Also in the most general case `az`, `bz`, `cz` and `dz` are _not_ zero. You would have to choose three of the four points to define one plane, and then another three for the next plane.

Answer (score 2):

A plane can be defined by a unit normal vector `(nx,ny,nz)` and a scalar distance from the origin `d` such that the equation of the plane is `nx*x+ny*y+nz*z=d`. You need to get the plane from 3 points to this format in order to proceed. If you don't know how you can look up *finding a plane from three points*.

Now the line can be specified by a unit direction vector `(ex,ey,ez)` and some point along the line `(rx,ry,rz)`

1. Find the product `s=(nx*ex+ny*ey+nz*ez)`. If it is zero then there is no intersection
2. Find the distance of the intersection to the point on the line `t=(d-(nx*rx+ny*ry+nz*rz))/s`
3. The intersection point is at `c=(rx+ex*t, ry+ey*t, rz+ez*t)`