# Python Find all points where a mesh intersects a plane

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I have verts and faces generated by `skimage.measure.marching_cubes`. How to find all points where a mesh intersects a plane? I would like to get something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348495/three-js-find-all-points-where-a-mesh-intersects-a-plane) but
on python and scikit-image

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the answer you referred, your starting point should be similar and the steps will be the same, regardless of python or javascript.
Without example code it will be difficult to determine what part of it gives you problems.

By looping over the faces (consisting of 3 points if triangles) of the mesh and checking if and where each edge (v1, v2) intersects with the plane, you will get good result, depending on your use case. See here for an implementation of that intersection:
[3D Line-Plane Intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666222/3d-line-plane-intersection)

I can supply specific implementation details if you give a minimal reproducible code example with a mesh and a plane.